# Getting array input key and value using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to get unique id and map it to value from array input using jquery/javascript

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="parameter['abc']" value="first value">
<input type="text" name="parameter['zxv']" value="second value">
```

Required output

```
[
'abc' : 'first value'
'zxv' : 'second value'
]
```

My attempts: managed to get values, but not indexes.

```
$('input[name^="parameter"]').map(function(){return 
$(this).val();}).get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = {};
$.each($(".inputs"), function(key1, index1) {
  var res = $(this).attr('name').split("parameter");
  var parameterkey = res[1];
  var res = parameterkey.replace("['", "");
  var resd = res.replace("']", "");
  var key = resd;
  var value = $(this).val();
  obj[key] = value;
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inputs" type="text" name="parameter['abc']" value="first value">
<input class="inputs" type="text" name="parameter['zxv']" value="second value">
```